# Method updateGames In Class GamesActivity Cannot Be App

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am attempting to update a SQLite database table with some additional EditText fields from a Dialog. How ever I am getting the following error message for all five of the lines that are updating the Games Table.

error: method updateGames in class GamesActivity cannot be app
error: method updateGames in class GamesActivity cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,int,int,int,int,int,int,String
found: String,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I understand that I have more than likely create the argument for my updateGame method incorrectly.  Since I am fairly new to Javascript and Android programming I cannot seem to find a way to correct this.  When I look in my DatabaseHelper I can see that the method is never called or used.  I am assuming that this is due to my arguments being wrong.

I have listed my code below.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone could have a look and point out what I am doing incorrectly.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
import rvogl.ca.tpcui.Database.Models.Bowler;
import rvogl.ca.tpcui.Database.Models.League;
import rvogl.ca.tpcui.Database.Models.Series;
import rvogl.ca.tpcui.Database.Models.Games;
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tpc_database";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(League.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(Bowler.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(Series.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(Games.CREATE_TABLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + League.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Series.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Games.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //League Methods
    public long insertLeague(String league) {
        //Get Writable Database That We Want To Write Data Too
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(League.COLUMN_NAME, league);
        long id = db.insert(League.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
        return id;
    }

    public League getLeague(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(League.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{League.COLUMN_ID, League.COLUMN_NAME, League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                League.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        League league = new League(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));
        cursor.close();
        return league;
    }

    public List<League> getAllLeagues() {
        List<League> leagues = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + League.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
                League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                League league = new League();
                league.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_ID)));
                league.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_NAME)));
                league.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(League.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

                leagues.add(league);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return leagues;
    }

    public int getLeaguesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + League.TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }

    public int updateLeague(League league) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(League.COLUMN_NAME, league.getName());
        return db.update(League.TABLE_NAME, values, League.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(league.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteLeague(League league) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(League.TABLE_NAME, League.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(league.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    //Bowler Methods
    public long insertBowler(String bowler) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME, bowler);
         long id = db.insert(Bowler.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
         db.close();

         return id;
    }
    public Bowler getBowler(long id) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.query(Bowler.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Bowler.COLUMN_ID, Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Bowler.COLUMN_NAME, Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                Bowler.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Bowler bowler = new Bowler(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_ID)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));
        cursor.close();
        return bowler;
    }
    public List<Bowler> getAllBowlers() {
        List<Bowler> bowlers = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
                Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Bowler bowler = new Bowler();
                bowler.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_ID)));
                bowler.setLeagueId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)));
                bowler.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME)));
                bowler.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

                bowlers.add(bowler);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return bowlers;
    }

    public int getBowlersCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }

    public int updateBowler(Bowler bowler) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME, bowler.getName());
        return db.update(Bowler.TABLE_NAME, values, Bowler.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(bowler.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteBowler(Bowler bowler) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Bowler.TABLE_NAME, Bowler.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(bowler.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    //Series Methods
    public long insertSeries(String series) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Series.COLUMN_NAME, series);
        long id = db.insert(Series.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
        return id;
    }

    public Series getSeries(long id) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.query(Series.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Series.COLUMN_ID, Series.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Series.COLUMN_NAME, Series.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                Series.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        Series series = new Series(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_ID)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));
        cursor.close();
        return series;
    }

    public List<Series> getAllSeries() {
        List<Series> series = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Series.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
                Series.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //Looping Through All Rows And Adding To The List
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Series series1 = new Series();
                series1.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_ID)));
                series1.setLeagueId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)));
                series1.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_NAME)));
                series1.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

                series.add(series1);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return series;
    }

    public int getSeriesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Series.TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }
    public int updateSeries(Series series) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Series.COLUMN_NAME, series.getName());
        return db.update(Series.TABLE_NAME, values, Series.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(series.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteSeries(Series series) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Series.TABLE_NAME, Series.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(series.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    //Games Methods
    public long insertGames(String games) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_SCORE, getGamesCount());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_STRIKES, getGamesCount());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_SPARES, getGamesCount());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_SPLITS, getGamesCount());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS, getGamesCount());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES, getGamesCount());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, getGamesCount());
        long id = db.insert(Games.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
        return id;
    }
    public Games getGames(long id) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.query(Games.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Games.COLUMN_ID, Games.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Games.COLUMN_SCORE, Games.COLUMN_STRIKES, Games.COLUMN_SPARES, Games.COLUMN_SPLITS, Games.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS, Games.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES, Games.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                Series.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        Games games = new Games(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_ID)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SCORE)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_STRIKES)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SPARES)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SPLITS)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SPARES)));

         cursor.close();
         return games;
    }

    public List<Games> getAllGames() {
        List<Games> games = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Games.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
                Games.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Games games1 = new Games();
                games1.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_ID)));
                games1.setLeagueId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)));
                games1.setScore(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SCORE)));
                games1.setStrikes(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_STRIKES)));
                games1.setSpares(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SPARES)));
                games1.setSplits(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SPLITS)));
                games1.setSplitConversions(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS)));
                games1.setOpenFrames(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES)));
```

games1.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Games.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

```
                games.add(games1);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return games;
    }

    public int getGamesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Games.TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }

    public int updateGames(Games games) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_SCORE, games.getScore());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_STRIKES, games.getStrikes());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_SPARES, games.getSpares());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_SPLITS, games.getSplits());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS, games.getSplitConversions());
        values.put(Games.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES, games.getOpenFrames());

         return db.update(Games.TABLE_NAME, values, Games.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(games.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteGames(Games games) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Games.TABLE_NAME, Games.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(games.getId())});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Database.Models.Games.java

```
public class Games {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Games";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID = "league_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCORE = "score";
    public static final String COLUMN_STRIKES = "strikes";
    public static final String COLUMN_SPARES = "spare";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES = "openframes";
    public static final String COLUMN_SPLITS = "plits";
    public static final String COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS = "splitconversions";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    private int id;
    private int league_id;
    private int score;
    private int strikes;
    private int spares;
    private int openframes;
    private int splits;
    private int splitconversions;
    private String timestamp;
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_SCORE + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_STRIKES + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_SPARES + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_SPLITS + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                    + ")";
     public Games(int anInt, int cursorInt, int i, int anInt1, int cursorInt1, int i1, int anInt2, int cursorInt2, String string, int i2) {
    }
    public Games() {
        this.id = id;
        this.league_id = league_id;
        this.score = score;
        this.strikes = strikes;
        this.spares = spares;
        this.openframes = openframes;
        this.splits = splits;
        this.splitconversions = splitconversions;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public int getLeagueId() { return league_id; }
    public int getScore() { return score; }
    public int getStrikes() { return strikes; }
    public int getSpares() { return spares; }
    public int getOpenFrames() { return openframes; }
    public int getSplits() { return splits; }
    public int getSplitConversions() { return splitconversions; }
    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
 public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 public void setLeagueId(int league_id) {
        this.league_id = league_id;
    }
    public void setScore(int score) { this.score = score; }
    public void setStrikes(int strikes) { this.strikes = strikes; }
    public void setSpares(int spares) { this.spares = spares; }
    public void setOpenFrames(int openframes) { this.openframes = openframes; }
    public void setSplits(int splits) { this.splits = splits; }
    public void setSplitConversions(int splitconversions) { this.splitconversions = splitconversions; }
    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
```

GamesActivity.java

```
    public class GamesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private GamesAdapter mAdapter;
        private List<Games> gamesList = new ArrayList<>();
        private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private TextView noGamesView;
        private DatabaseHelper db;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_games);
            coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            noGamesView = findViewById(R.id.empty_games_view);
            db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            gamesList.addAll(db.getAllGames());

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_games_fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showGamesDialog(false, null, -1);
                }
            });
            mAdapter = new GamesAdapter(this, gamesList);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            toggleEmptyGames();
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                    recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                    showActionsDialog(position);
                }
            }));
        }

         private void createGames(String games) {
             long id = db.insertGames(games);
             Games n = db.getGames(id);
             if (n != null) {
                 gamesList.add(0, n);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                toggleEmptyGames();
            }
        }
        private void updateGames(int score, int strikes, int spares, int splits, int splitconversions, int openframes, int position, String timestamp) {
            Games n = gamesList.get(position);
            n.setScore(score);
            n.setStrikes(strikes);
            n.setSpares(spares);
            n.setSplits(splits);
            n.setSplitConversions(splitconversions);
            n.setOpenFrames(openframes);
            n.setTimestamp(timestamp);
            db.updateGames(n);
            gamesList.set(position, n);
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            toggleEmptyGames();
        }
        private void deleteGames(int position) {
            db.deleteGames(gamesList.get(position));
            gamesList.remove(position);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            toggleEmptyGames();
        }
        private void showActionsDialog(final int position) {
            CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose option");
            builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == 0) {
                        showGamesDialog(true, gamesList.get(position), position);
                    } else {
                        deleteGames(position);
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

         private void showGamesDialog(final boolean shouldUpdate, final Games games, final int position) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.dialog_game, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(GamesActivity.this);
            alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(view);
            final EditText inputScore = view.findViewById(R.id.etScore);
            final EditText inputStrikes = view.findViewById(R.id.etStrikes);
            final EditText inputSpares = view.findViewById(R.id.etSpares);
            final EditText inputSplits = view.findViewById(R.id.etSplits);
            final EditText inputSplitConversions = view.findViewById(R.id.etSplitConversions);
            final EditText inputOpenFrames = view.findViewById(R.id.etOpenFrames);
            TextView dialogTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
            dialogTitle.setText(!shouldUpdate ? "Enter Game Stats" : "Edit Game Stats");
     if (shouldUpdate && games != null) {
                inputScore.setText(games.getScore());
                inputStrikes.setText(games.getStrikes());
                inputSpares.setText(games.getSpares());
                inputSplits.setText(games.getSplits());
                inputSplitConversions.setText(games.getSplitConversions());
                inputOpenFrames.setText(games.getOpenFrames());
            }
            alertDialogBuilderUserInput
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(shouldUpdate ? "update" : "save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                       }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                                    dialogBox.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
            alertDialog.show();

 alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (shouldUpdate && games != null) {

                         updateGames(inputScore.getText().toString(), position);
                        updateGames(inputStrikes.getText().toString(), position);
                        updateGames(inputSpares.getText().toString(), position);
                        updateGames(inputSplits.getText().toString(), position);
                        updateGames(inputSplitConversions.getText().toString(), position);
                        updateGames(inputOpenFrames.getText().toString(), position);

                    } else {
                         createGames(inputScore.getText().toString());
                        createGames(inputStrikes.getText().toString());
                        createGames(inputSpares.getText().toString());
                        createGames(inputSplits.getText().toString());
                        createGames(inputSplitConversions.getText().toString());
                        createGames(inputOpenFrames.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        private void toggleEmptyGames() {
            if (db.getGamesCount() > 0) {
                noGamesView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                noGamesView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need anything further to assist me, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks as though you should be replacing :-

```
        updateGames(inputScore.getText().toString(), position);
        updateGames(inputStrikes.getText().toString(), position);
        updateGames(inputSpares.getText().toString(), position);
        updateGames(inputSplits.getText().toString(), position);
        updateGames(inputSplitConversions.getText().toString(), position);
        updateGames(inputOpenFrames.getText().toString(), position);
```

with :-

```
        updateGames(
            Integer.parseInt(inputScore.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(inputScore.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(inputSpares.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(inputSplits.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(inputSplitConversions.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(inputOpenFrames.getText().toString()),
            position, 
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) //<<<<< FORMAT GUESSED
        );
```

This will then suit the signature of the `updateGames` method i.e. :-

```
    private void updateGames(
            int score, 
            int strikes, 
            int spares, 
            int splits, 
            int splitconversions, 
            int openframes, 
            int position, 
            String timestamp) {

        Games n = gamesList.get(position);
        n.setScore(score);
        n.setStrikes(strikes);
        n.setSpares(spares);
        n.setSplits(splits);
        n.setSplitConversions(splitconversions);
        n.setOpenFrames(openframes);
        n.setTimestamp(timestamp);
        db.updateGames(n);
        gamesList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        toggleEmptyGames();
    }
```

- Which uses `db.updateGames(n);` to update the database.
- If the values in the EditText's are incorrect (e.g. they must be only numeric) then you would get a parse exception.
- **Note** you may have to play around with the format of the timestamp to suit.
- **Also** this is in-principle code and has not been tested.